# to estimate time and labor efforts for a task completion

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-choice, idiomatic-language

Could you please tell me whether the selected sentence

> Ability **to estimate time and labor efforts for a task completion**

sounds natural? I don't want it to sound informal, instead I want it to be quite formal.

Comment: Thanks! What's the right term for it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correctly understanding what you're trying to say, any of these would be correct ways to write the phrase:

- *"ability to estimate time and labor required for task completion"*
- *"ability to estimate time and labor required to complete the task"*
- *"ability to estimate time and labor required to complete tasks"*

However none of these are complete sentences (nor is your original example). To use this phrase in a sentence, you would need a subject/verb. For example:

- *"**I was impressed by her** ability to estimate time and labor required to complete the task."*
- *"**The candidate must have the** ability to estimate time and labor required for task completion."*
- *"**I have the** ability to estimate time and labor required for task completion."*